# What kind of web effects are out there?

Tags: css, effects

Like rounded corner,any more?

Comment: you might consider google, or just go surfing.  It's not like web effects are invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Is it me or do people not use google ?
http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html

Comment: What is this "google" you speak of?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For CSS3:

```
.box { border:1px solid black; border-radius:15px; -moz-border-radius:15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; }
```

See http://afifoam.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should consider studying some more CSS and CSS scripting and maybe some graphic design, although you can find some ideas here:

[CSS Zengarden](http://csszengarden.com/)

[CSS3 preview](http://www.css3.info/)

In general with CSS3 there are some new features like:

- rounded corners
- font shadow
- custom fonts
- box shadow
- text overflow